# model popup is not showing from server side in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to show popup model from server side but its not working. I don't know where i am doing wrong. My webform page is inherit from Master Page.All the bootstrap files are included in master file header. Below is the client side code of web form page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UploadDocument.aspx.cs" Inherits="DMS_WebApp.UploadDocument" %>




<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <section class="panel">
        <header class="panel-heading">
            Upload Documents
        </header>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table table-striped table-advance table-hover" AutoGenerateColumns="true"
                                Style="max-width: 500px">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" OnClick="Edit" class="btn btn-primary" />

                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                </Columns>

                            </asp:GridView>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Bootstrap Modal Dialog -->

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upModal" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblModalTitle" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblModalBody" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Server side code is below:

```
    protected void Add(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

       ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "myModal", "$('#myModal').modal('show');", true);
        upModal.Update();

    }
```

Comment: Did you do any basic debugging? Check the JavaScript console in your browsers for errors? Verify that the ID's in the resulting HTML match what you expect etc? If you did these things, your error should become apparently fairly quickly. Why haven't you shown where you trigger the `Add` method in your question? Anyways, why do you need a postback to the server just to return some JavaScript to the client side to execute? Why not run that on the client and ditch the UpdatePanel?

Comment: Your confusing client-side with server-side. Your server code actually calls a client-side jquery, which is pointless if all you're wanting to do is show the Modal. I am writing an answer for your below now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using server-side code to control client-side controls is not good programming. If you can keep all your client-side calls on the client's browser, and away from the server, the better. Unfortunately not all situations afford this, and at times we have to use server-side scripting to control client browser functionality, for good UX and other business reasons.

For example:

Lets' say you want a popup form to give the user the ability to create new logins...

Here's a sample:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upADDMAIN" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnADD" runat="server" Text="NEW LOGIN" BackColor="Blue" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFCC" OnClick="btnADD_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnDUM" runat="server" style="display:none" />
        <div style="height:20px">
        </div>
        <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeADD" runat="server"
            targetcontrolid="btnDUM" 
            popupcontrolid="pnlADD" 
            backgroundcssclass="modelbackground">    
        </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlADD" runat="server" Width="750px" HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="auto-style10" Height="250px">
            <div class="hdr" id="puHDR">
                <div class="text-center" style="background-color: #FFCC66; height:30px; vertical-align:middle">
                    <strong style="background-color: #FFCC66; vertical-align: middle;">ENTER NEW LOGIN DETAILS</strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="auto-style31" id="puBDY">
                <table style="padding: 2px; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;" class="auto-style4">
                    <tr style="text-align:left;height:10px">
                        <td class="auto-style32" style="vertical-align: top; " colspan="4"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="text-align:left;">
                        <td class="auto-style5" style="vertical-align: top; width: 5%;"></td>
                        <td class="auto-style2" style="vertical-align: top"><strong>POTL Login ID</strong></td>
                        <td class="auto-style7" style="vertical-align: top">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLOGIN" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vgAdd"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtLogin" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="* Required" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="vgAdd"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:CustomValidator ID="cv1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtLOGIN" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="This login already exits!" OnServerValidate="cv1_ServerValidate" ValidateEmptyText="true" ValidationGroup="vgAdd"></asp:CustomValidator>
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style3" style="width: 10%;">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbISActive" runat="server" Checked="True" CssClass="myCheckBox" TabIndex="4" Text="Active?  " TextAlign="Left" ValidationGroup="vgAdd" Width="100%" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="text-align:left;height:40px">
                        <td class="auto-style25" style="vertical-align: top; width: 5%;">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td class="auto-style18" style="vertical-align: top"><strong>Password</strong></td>
                        <td class="auto-style36" style="vertical-align: top">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPWD" runat="server" 
                                TextMode="Password"
                                ToolTip="Enter at least an 8 character password with a mix of numbers, capitals, and letters."
                                ValidationGroup="vgAdd" TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbShow" runat="server" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="txtPWD" 
                                ErrorMessage="* Required" 
                                ValidationGroup="vgAdd" 
                                Display="Dynamic"
                                SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 10%;" class="auto-style37">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="text-align:left;height:40px">
                        <td class="auto-style25" style="vertical-align: top; width: 5%;">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td class="auto-style18" style="vertical-align: top"><strong>Password (CONFIRM)</strong></td>
                        <td class="auto-style36" style="vertical-align: top">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPWDCONF" runat="server" 
                                TextMode="Password"
                                ToolTip="Enter at least an 8 character password with a mix of numbers, capitals, and letters." 
                                ValidationGroup="vgAdd" TabIndex="2"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="txtPWDCONF" 
                                ErrorMessage="* Required" 
                                SetFocusOnError="True" 
                                Display="Dynamic"
                                ValidationGroup="vgAdd"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="txtPWDCONF" 
                                ValidationGroup="vgAdd" 
                                SetFocusOnError="true"
                                Display="Dynamic"
                                ControlToCompare="txtPWD" 
                                ErrorMessage="Passwords do not match!" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 10%;" class="auto-style37">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="text-align:left;">
                        <td class="auto-style27" style="vertical-align: top; width: 5%;"></td>
                        <td class="auto-style28" style="vertical-align: top;"><strong>Default Agent</strong></td>
                        <td class="auto-style29" style="vertical-align: top;">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAgent" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Width="370px"
                                DataSourceID="sdsDEBmaster2" DataTextField="AgentName" DataValueField="AgentID" ValidationGroup="vgAdd" TabIndex="3">
                                <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">Select...</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsDEBmaster2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SpotConnectionString %>" 
                                SelectCommand="SELECT ...blahblah"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 10%;" class="auto-style30">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvddl0" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="ddlAgent" 
                                InitialValue="0" 
                                ErrorMessage="* Required" 
                                ValidationGroup="vgAdd" 
                                Display="Dynamic"
                                SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="text-align:left;height:40px">
                        <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align: top; " colspan="4">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnOK" runat="server" 
                                CausesValidation="true" 
                                OnClick="btnOK_Click" 
                                style="width: 80px" 
                                TabIndex="5" 
                                Text="OK" 
                                UseSubmitBehavior="true" 
                                ValidationGroup="vgAdd" />
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <asp:Button ID="btnCAN" runat="server" 
                                CausesValidation="False" 
                                OnClick="btnCAN_Click" 
                                style="width: 80px" 
                                TabIndex="6" 
                                Text="CANCEL" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Ignore the validators, but they're handy to know in these situations.

As you can see I have an `UpdatePanel` surrounding the whole lot, an `MPE` control and a `Panel` control which has my form controls (no need to actually create an asp:form control!).

Code behind...

```
protected void btnADD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClearADDform();
            mpeADD.Show(); //show the MPE control when the user has clicked the ADD button control
        }

        protected void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Page.Validate("vgAdd");
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
//blahblah

                    //hide the mpe
                    mpeADD.Hide();

                    //reload the page
                    Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", "alert('" + exc.Message + "');", true);
                }
            }
            else
                //show the mpe and continue showing until either CANCEL or fields are validated
                mpeADD.Show();
        }

        protected void btnCAN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mpeADD.Hide();
        }

        protected void ClearADDform()
        {
            txtLOGIN.Text = string.Empty;
            cbISActive.Checked = true;
            txtPWD.Text = string.Empty;
            ddlAgent.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
```

So a very rudimentary example of how to manage AjaxControlToolKit's ModalPopupExtender control from both client and server-side.

Comment: @user1891251 thanks! Could you please UP vote my answer then? Thanks again

Comment: @Fandango68 he has not privileges to Up Vote see.